# How should I write a method that might be run only once or any number of times, but I want some logic to be run only once when the method is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Strange question, I know. Allow me to explain.

I have a JavaScript/jQuery function that is used to handle checkbox changes. here's some pseudo-code (FYI, I'm not actually trying to get the number of red rows - this is just PSEUDO CODE):

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].option").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("div.special").removeClass("red");
    }
    else {
        $("div.special").addClass("red");
    }

    // I only want to call this after all the checkbox event have been handled
    updateNumRedDivs();
});

function updateNumRedDivs() {
    alert($("div.special.red").length+"red DIVs found");
}
```

Now, the checkbox handler can be called either when an individual checkbox is clicked (obviously), or when a separate "Select All" checkbox is called:

```
$(".myForm .selectAllCheckbox").change(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(this).closest("form").find("input[type='checkbox'].option");

    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $checkboxes.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).attr("checked"))
                $(this).attr("checked", "checked").change();
        });
    }

    updateNumRedDivs();
});
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still confused. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I think I've figured out what he means... He has some function `updateNumRedDivs` which he wants to run after all `change` methods are called.  This could mean one `checkbox` changes then it should run, or a whole bunch are changed programatically but he only wants to call the function after all are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the solution I came up with - not pretty, but it gets the job done:

```
$(".myForm input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selectAllCheckbox") {
        var $checkboxes = $(this).closest("form").find("input[type='checkbox'].option");

        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $checkboxes.each(function() {
                if (!$(this).attr("checked"))
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked").change();
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("div.special").removeClass("red");
        }
        else {
            $("div.special").addClass("red");
        }
    }

    updateNumRedDivs();
});

function updateNumRedDivs() {
    alert($("div.special.red").length+"red DIVs found");
}
```

Basically, I consolidated into one change handler, and made it recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Separate the logic for the individual checkbox change handler into two functions.  Then, for select all, just call the function you want, rather than invoking `change()`:

```
function changeHandler(chkBox) {
    if (chkBox.is(":checked")) {
        $("div.special").removeClass("red");
    }
    else {
        $("div.special").addClass("red");
    }
}
$("input[type='checkbox'].option").change(function() {
    changeHandler($(this));
    updateNumRedDivs();
});

function updateNumRedDivs() {
    alert($("div.special.red").length+"red DIVs found");
}

$(".myForm .selectAllCheckbox").change(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(this).closest("form").find("input[type='checkbox'].option");

    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $checkboxes.each(function() {
            if (!$(this).attr("checked"))
                changeHandler($(this).attr("checked", "checked"));
        });
    }

    updateNumRedDivs();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to run once, just destroy the reference at the bottom of the function.

```
var updateNumRedDivs = function() {
    // ... actual handling here
    updateNumRedDivs = function(){};
}
```

Multiple times, I'd use a closure, like so

```
// This will run five times, before destroying
var updateNumRedDivs = function(amount) {
    var calls = 0;
    return function () {
        // handle event
        if (++calls === amount) updateNumRedDivs = function() {};
    };
}(5)
```

**Edit:**
May have misunderstood your intent with a function that runs once or any number of times. Are you looking for a function that only runs once from every source, or a function that will not be limited by total calls, but instead by *n* calls from a single source?

Comment: +1 because I think this perfectly answers the question as phrased in its title, but based on the detailed question text and example code I suspect the requirement is a bit different (but I don't understand the real requirement).

Answer (score 0):

> Too Much Of Code
>   Alright you don't want the Change event of the Single Check Box fired when you select the Select ALL CheckBox

```
var SelectALLFired=false;
```

> In the handler of the SelectALLCheckBox Make the value for SelectALLFired=true; and upon completion change the value back to SelectALLFired=false;

on the Single CheckBox Change function before doing anything  write an If Statement

```
if(!SelectALLFired)
{
Your Code
}

$(".myForm .selectAllCheckbox").change(function() {
SelectALLFired=true;
var $checkboxes = $(this).closest("form").find("input[type='checkbox'].option");

if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
    $checkboxes.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).attr("checked"))
            $(this).attr("checked", "checked").change();
    });
}
    SelectALLFired = false;

updateNumRedDivs();
```

})

```
$("input[type='checkbox'].option").change(function() {
if(!SelectALLFired)
{
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $("div.special").removeClass("red");
    }
    else {
       $("div.special").addClass("red");
    }
}
// I only want to call this after all the checkbox event have been handled
updateNumRedDivs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by passing extra params to the change event through `trigger`:

NOTE: dumbed down to illustrate the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/bnWVd/

```
function doit(){
    alert("done");   
}

$("input").click(function(event,extraParams){
    // do stuff
    if(extraParams && extraParams.noAlert){
       // do nothing or maybe something else
    }else{
        doit(); 
    }
});

$("button").click(function(){
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).trigger("click",{noAlert: true});
    }); 

    doit();
});
```

Basically, when called in the loop I pass a parameter to the event letting it know not to run the extra function.  Then when the loop is done I call it directly.  If no parameter is passed it will be called.